# What frequency range would be ideal for audible communication on a planet with a thick atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, communication, audio

If you lived on a planet with a very thick atmosphere, and you communicated verbally, what frequency range would be best? What would you eventually evolve to?

Would their voices need to be high pitched or deep bass? ultrasonic?

Comment: Welcome to the site Ralph Rotten, when you have a few minutes, please take the [tour] and read up in our [help] about how we work: [ask]. Could you explain what you mean by "thick"? Are you asking about high atmospheric density? You would also need to tell us the atmospheric composition, ie the mixture of gasses. Different gasses have varying speeds of sound at different pressures. Voting to put on hold as "unclear what you are asking" in order to give you time to [edit] your question.

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  As written, this question is going to get closed as too broad or [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437/40609) just for the question "what would you eventually evolve to?"  Stack exchange is one-specific-question/one-best answer.  What one, specific question do you have? (what they evolve into is not specific.)

Comment: How thick is very thick? Is Earth's atmosphere thick or is it thin? Can you describe the atmosphere with more specific words -- what's the pressure, temperature, gas composition?

Comment: Hi Ralph, this is not a bad question, it just needs more details so we can answer it.  Don't worry about the question getting closed; if you edit it well, we can vote to reopen it.  The "on hold" period is to give you time to make it a stronger question.

Comment: Note that air density won't affect anyone's hearing, so whatever frequency range is "best" will have to be within the normal human range, say 40 to 8000 Hz.

Comment: And note that the frequency of the human voice _is_ affected by air density.

Comment: If you tell us 2 or more of pressure, density and component gases (specifically to get molar mass), this can be answered specifically. I suspect it will have an answer with a single boundary – no higher than some limit, but it can be as low as you want (low frequency is basically just sending pulses) – but it's early in the morning here and I'm liable to be wrong. Maybe consider adding the hard-science tag?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a read of this section of an article on outdoor sound propagation: [Attenuation by atmospheric absorption](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Acoustics/Outdoor_Sound_Propagation#Attenuation_by_atmospheric_absorption[5]_[6]_[7]) (or a vaguely related [physics SE question which brough that article to my attention)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87751/do-low-frequency-sounds-really-carry-longer-distances). There are some fairly hairy formulae in there, and an important caveat "*The formulas, are valid for a pressure under 2 atm, a temperature under 330 K and up to an altitude of 3 km*" but one may extrapolate from that, especially as you're not asking for hard science.

TL;DR: *the absorption coefficient is higher for a higher frequency and/or a higher pressure.*

High frequency sounds will carry less well in higher pressure air. If you want to be able to shout as far, you'll need a deeper voice. I can't tell you which frequency range would be best without knowing about the atmospheric composition and pressure, and what metrics you'd use for "best" anyway.